# Push tikz nodes to the axis limits as much as possible

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, axis

I would like to place nodes to straight lines as close as possible to the axis limits but still in the axis, regardless of the length of the node text. While I was able to do this for labels that reach the maximum x-value first using `restrict domain`, it does not work for those that reach the maximum y-value first. The reason is that the anchor `north east` reaches it before the anchor `south east` does. However, if change the anchor then the text shifts to the other side of the line which I would prefer not to have.

Is there a way to do this without positioning the node manually using `pos=x` as I did for "Slope 6"? Calculating x is possible but how to convert the height of the node into axis coordinates?

Many thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1.5pt,scale=1.4]
\begin{axis}[xmin=3.0, xmax=8.0, ymin=10.0, ymax=35.0,
restrict x to domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
restrict y to domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},samples=200]
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{3*x} node [at end,draw,anchor=south east,sloped] () {\scriptsize Slope 3};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{4*x} node [at end,draw,anchor=south east,sloped] () {\scriptsize Slope 4};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{5*x} node [at end,draw,anchor=south east,sloped] () {\scriptsize Slope 5};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{6*x} node [pos=.9,draw,anchor=south east,sloped] () {\scriptsize Slope 6};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{7*x} node [at end,draw,anchor=south east,sloped] () {\scriptsize Slope 7};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc` to compute the position.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1.5pt,box/.style={draw,font=\scriptsize}]
\begin{axis}[xmin=3.0, xmax=8.0, ymin=10.0, ymax=35.0,,scale=1.4,
restrict x to domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},
restrict y to domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},samples=200]
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{3*x}
node [at end,box,anchor=south east,sloped] (s3) {Slope 3};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{4*x} 
node [at end,box,anchor=south east,sloped] (s4) {Slope 4};
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{5*x} 
coordinate[pos=0] (p50) coordinate[pos=1] (p51);
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{6*x} 
coordinate[pos=0] (p60) coordinate[pos=1] (p61);
\addplot[domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}]{7*x} 
coordinate[pos=0] (p70) coordinate[pos=1] (p71);
\end{axis}
\path (current axis.north west) coordinate (NW)
      (current axis.north east) coordinate (NE)
     let \p1=($(s3.north)-(s3.south)$),
    \p5=($(p51)-(p50)$),\n5={atan2(\y5,\x5)},
    \p6=($(p61)-(p60)$),\n6={atan2(\y6,\x6)},
    \p7=($(p71)-(p70)$),\n7={atan2(\y7,\x7)}
    in
    foreach \X in {5,6,7}
    {($(intersection of p\X0--p\X1 and NW--NE)+(\n\X+180:{(\y1+1pt)/tan(\n\X)})$)
    node[box,anchor=south east,rotate=\n\X]{Slope \X}}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that if you *really* want to use `scale`, use it in the options of the `axis`, not in the ambient `tikzpicture`. In most situations one does not really need it, one can adjust the `width` and `height` of the axis, but I kept it in.

Comment: I accept it because it solves this very problem, even though I was hoping for a more general solution.